# RQT_CLOSE when flashing TWRP into Samsung Galaxy A8 (2018) with Odin

Tags: twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-a8-2018

I am trying to flash TWRP into my Samsung Galaxy A8 (2018) based on official instructions from:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-a8-2018/samsung-galaxy-a8-2018-roms-kernels-recoveries--other-development/recovery-twrp-3-2-2-0-galaxy-a8-2018-t3818201

I have followed the instructions carefully and repeated several times. I initially tried things on linux with adb and heimdall, however heimdall was failing to flash, so I returned back to the exact Windows instructions using Odin3 v3.13.1. When I try to flash twrp-3.4.0-0-jackpotlte.img.tar into my Samsung Galaxy A8 (2018) aka SM-A530F, Odin fails consistently with this log:

```
<ID:0/006> Added!!
<ID:0/006> Odin engine v(ID:3.1301)..
<ID:0/006> File analysis..
<ID:0/006> Total Binary size: 35 M
<ID:0/006> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/006> Initialzation..
<ID:0/006> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/006> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/006> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/006> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/006> recovery.img
<ID:0/006> RQT_CLOSE !!
<ID:0/006> 
<ID:0/006> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/006> Removed!!
```

I believe my phone is not RMM locked because I see Developer Options in my settings. I tried the process with OEM unlocking enabled and disabled in my phone Dev Options. No success yet.
I googled the issue for a few hours, however people mostly report seeing RQT_CLOSE when phone is RMM locked, which I believe is not my case. Maybe this is related to the recent Android update I installed yesterday.

Phone software:

```
Android 9
Baseband version: A530FXXUECTH1
Kernel version: 
 - 4.4.111-19323942
 - #1 Mon Aug 3 15:36:52 KST 2020
Build number: PPR1.180610.011.A530FXXUECTH2
Security patch level: August 1,2020
Security software verion:
 - ASKS v3.1.1 Rlease 20200120
 - ADP v3.0 Releasae 20191001
 - SMR Aug-2020 Release 1
```

What does RQT_CLOSE actually mean? Could you please help investigate?